# The Spring profile property values being overridden in yaml file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml, spring-profiles

So my property file looks like:-

```
spring:
 profiles:
   active: {SPRING_PROFILE:default}
---
spring:
 application:
   name: application-mode1
 config:
   activate:
     on-profile: mode1
config:
 filter:
  ruleId: 1
---
spring:
 application:
   name: application-mode2
 config:
   activate:
     on-profile: mode2
config:
 filter:
  ruleId: 2
```

I am setting the SPRING_PROFILE value at runtime. So there is two deployment of same application in same environment. The two profiles(mode1, mode2) are getting mapped to specific deployments as the spring starter log "message":"The following profiles are active: mode1", suggested but when it comes to fetching the ruleId only the last mentioned and updated value is getting fetched by both the apps not the profile specific rule id. In this case it is 2 but if I reverse this it will be 1 for both the apps. kindly suggest any alternative. This app is deployed using kubernetes.

Comment: Other than a missing dollar sign for `${SPRING_PROFILE:default}` I don't see anything wrong. I copied your config to a new Spring boot project, fixed the missing `$`, ran it with the profiles and it worked fine.

Comment: Yeah I have added the dollar sign in original code.

Comment: But it still doesn't work, even with the dollar sign? Because if we can't reproduce it from the code you posted, there must be something else going on.

Comment: I figured that my springboot is 2.3 will there be any change for spring 2.3 in this code or will it work for that as well?

Comment: That's indeed the issue. The configuration you're using was introduced in Spring boot **2.4**. Before that you had to use other properties. See my answer for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The configuration you're using works only from **Spring boot 2.4** and higher (see [relevant blogpost](https://spring.io/blog/2020/08/14/config-file-processing-in-spring-boot-2-4)).

Before that, you had to use the `spring.profiles` property. For example:

```yaml
spring:
 profiles:
   active: ${SPRING_PROFILE:default} # The dollar sign was also missing
---
spring:
 application:
   name: application-mode1
 profiles: mode1
config:
 filter:
  ruleId: 1
---
spring:
 application:
   name: application-mode2
 profiles: mode2
config:
 filter:
  ruleId: 2
```

Comment: I have a question since I am trying to access my properties in @Configuration file directly using @value{"$config.filter.ruleId"} its not picking up the value should i need a external loader for this? Considering I was able to load properties like this earlier with spring profile implementation. Thanks!!